# Is there a simple SwiftUI way to hint that an action has been performed?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a generic tool In SwiftUI to confirm that an action has taken place? This is for an app on an iPhone, so I have no mouse, but the sort of thing I have in mind would otherwise look like a tool tip. It would be a short word such as 'save' or 'load', or perhaps an icon. It would be small, transparent, and temporary.

Buttons have animations, but I am not necessarily dealing with buttons. For example, I have the RGB and XYZ details of a colour shown in a panel. If I click on that panel, the text gets copied to the pasteboard. But, right now, the user has no feedback that anything has happened.

I bet they exist, and I haven't hit on the right word to search for them. Any ideas? Not an alert, or a popover, or a sheet, or a toaster. I would call it a 'hint' but that doesn't show up anything.

Comment: Plain and simple: add a checkmark. Alternatively you could add haptic feedback. `UINotificationFeedbackGenerator` provides a feedback for success, warning and error. You also can create your own feedback style. Downside: users can turn off haptic feedback. Have a look at the [human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/patterns/feedback)

Comment: Ooo! Haptics! I have never used those. I tried, and I liked the result. Unfortunately, having a finger to feel it interfered with some other gestures, so I could not use it this time. But it is a trick worth remembering. Thanks.  

I could have a checkmark. I would have to add it and take it away, which gets old when you have a table of them. What I wanted was some vague visual 'blip' like a haptic.

Comment: Apple hasn't a system solution. So you could create a toast like android does or add some sort of subtile flashing/alpha animation

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that I haven't missed something obvious. I could possibly make a haptic-like blip. But right now the whole world of phone apps is so alien, that I am sticking to what everyone uses.